# KeePass like program without password auth

Tags: database, keepass

I'm looking for a program that's like KeePass's UI, and self contained 1 database file, but without the master password requirement.

Essentially take KeePass, and remove the master password requirement.

**I'm not looking for a password manager, otherwise I'd just use KeePass. Instead I'm looking for something like KeePass' UI, but without the main password requirement.**

I will be using this for non-confidential data, but it's a great tool for sorting, searching and portability.

Anyone know of something?

Comment: That is a bad idea because if you don't have a master password, the passwords are stored in clear text or weak encrypted. Always remember if you don''t need a password, neither does an attacker! If you don't care about that, you can make an excel list.

Comment: I'm not looking for a password safe. If i was, I'd use KeePass. I'm looking for a self contained database with the UI of KeePass. Something like a contact manager? I dont know what you'd call it.

Comment: @Simon: Filesystem-level encryption.

Comment: @grawity what do you want to say with that? You need a key to encrypt the file/folder.

Comment: Edits made to question for clarity. Again, not looking for encryption, or passwords, or anything like that.

Comment: Just use KeePass and instead of a password, use your user account to unlock it.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg thought about that, but lacks portability, no? Can't stick it onto a USB stick and bring it to work because the user account UIDs would be different.

Comment: @Pat: Yeah, you're right. How about a key file then? The key file should be automatically selected when you open your database (as in, KeePass remembers the last used key file in the config). That works for me, but I use a composite key (key file + password). The key file can be anything you want. You could just place it in your KeePass folder. If that isn't an option, I'm out of ideas for now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Roboform I use it without a master password. It does auto-login for Firefox and IE.
You can make an entry not require the master password.

Comment: Don't see why Roboform would not work in your case...